# How to set height as auto while printing a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I need your help.

I am making a invoice coupon system and stuck in print on coupon printer. 
Can you tell me how can I set the height of paper to auto, which needs to be changed dynamically as per the content.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page 
{
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}
@media print {  
@page {  
  size:80mm 80mm;  
}  
}
```

Currently I am using 80mm 80mm , so width is ok but height cannot be 80 ? It should be auto adjustable.

I want to print it in rollup paper.

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Put the Invoice Container max-width: 80mm;
for ex:

```
<div id="invoiceContainer">
....

</div>
<style>
#invoiceContainer{
..
max-width: 80mm;
height:auto;/*min-height:80mm;*/
}
</style>
```

No need of @media print queries and don't have to put size inside it.

Comment: @AkshayBajpei have you removed the @@media print size and tried?

Comment: @AkshayBajpei have you checked with the printer settings. Go to the "Printer Settings" menu and choose "Roll Paper" as the paper source and have a try.